# Can I merge two Set objects in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, merge, set

I understand the [Set class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) has the merge method just as the Hash class does. However, the [Set#merge documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-merge) says:

> Merges the elements of the given enumerable object to the set and returns self.

It seems that merging can only take place between a Set and another non-Set object. Is that the case, or can I merge two sets as below?

```
set1.merge(set2)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Why This Question is Useful

While the OP has been criticized for lack of research effort, it should be pointed out that the Ruby documentation for [Set#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-merge) is not friendly for new Rubyists. As of Ruby 2.3.0, it says:

> Merges the elements of the given enumerable object to the set and returns self.

It offers `merge(enum)` as the signature, but no useful examples. If you need to know what classes mix in [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html), it can be difficult to grok from just this one piece of documentation what kind of duck-typed ducks can be merged in. For example, `set.merge {foo: 'bar'}.to_enum` will raise SyntaxError despite the fact that it *is* enumerable:

```
{foo: 'bar'}.to_enum.class
#=> Enumerator

{foo: 'bar'}.to_enum.class.include? Enumerable
#=> true
```

### Merging Sets

If you're thinking of [Set#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-merge) as creating a set union, then yes: you can merge sets. Consider the following:

```
require 'set'

set1 = Set.new [1, 2, 3]
#=> #<Set: {1, 2, 3}>

set2 = Set.new [3, 4, 5]
#=> #<Set: {3, 4, 5}>

set1.merge set2
#=> #<Set: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}>
```

### Merging Other Enumerable Objects Like Arrays

However, you can also merge other [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) objects (like arrays) into a set. For example:

```
set = Set.new [1, 2, 3]
#=> #<Set: {1, 2, 3}>

set.merge [3, 4, 5]
#=> #<Set: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}>
```

### Using Array Union Instead

Of course, you may not need sets at all. Compare and contrast Set to array unions ([Array#|](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-7C)). If you don't need the actual features of the Set class, you can often do similar things directly with arrays. For example:

```
([1, 2, 3, 4] | [3, 4, 5, 6]).uniq
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Another data point: `require 'set'; [1,2,3].to_set.merge({ a: 3, b: 4 }) #=> #<Set: {1, 2, 3, [:a, 3], [:b, 4]}>`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good example, although I'd tweak it to `[1,2,3].to_set.merge({ a: 3, b: 4 }.values)` to keep the Set numeric. But the parser can get very confused with sets. Since Set#merge doesn't have a block form, `[1,2,3].to_set.merge {a: 3, b: 4}` should work but doesn't, even though `{a: 3, b: 4}.class < Enumerable #=> true`. My guess is the Set library needs some TLC.